# CarrierWave with ActiveResource - custom storage engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, carrierwave, activeresource

I need help figuring out how to get CarrierWave to work with an ActiveResource object.  I am working on a project that currently uses CarrierWave on a standard ActiveRecord object which works very nicely.  However, we are migrating toward a remote file system so I need CarrierWave to work with ActiveResource objects.

I know that CarrierWave allows you to write your own storage engine rather than use say fog, file, or mongo grid_fs but I can't figure out what the flow for this process is.

Here is the state of my efforts:

ReportDocument class

```
class ReportDocument

  mount_uploader :merchant_geoip_image, ImageUploader

end
```

Uploader for CarrierWave

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  storage MyCustomStorageEngine

end
```

My custom storage engine

```
class MyCustomStorageEngine

  def store!(file)
   # do custom storage stuff with ActiveResource object here
  end

  def retrieve!(identifier)
   # do custom retrieval stuff with ActiveResource object here
  end

end
```

My issue is that I can't get CarrierWave to call my custom `store!` and `retrieve!` methods when I save the `ReportDocument` object.  The Mongoid ORM defines their storage engine as `gridFS` which can be found here:  https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave-mongoid/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/storage/grid_fs.rb

It doesn't seem like I'm doing anything different from the Mongoid ORM implementation.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.